# Solving explicitly $y(x)$ in an exact ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, implicit-function

Given the following differential equation:

$$y^2+(2xy+1)\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$

I have found that the solution is given implictly by:

$$ (\ast) \quad xy^2(x)+y(x)=k \: ; k \in \mathbb{R}$$

If I was interested in a domain that doesn't contain $0$, then I'd write that:
$$y(x)=\frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1+4kx}}{2x}$$ and $D_y=]-\frac{1}{4k},0[; k>0 \quad \quad
D_y=]0,-\frac{1}{4k}[; k<0$

For $k=0$; $y(x)=0 \lor y(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ would be two solutions for $(\ast)$. $$\\$$
But now if for all $k \in \mathbb{R}$; I was interested in a solution in an interval that contains $0$, what would be the general procedure?

Comment: Perhaps you also have an [initial condition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_value_problem) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution $$ y = \frac{-1 + \sqrt{1 + 4 k x}}{2x} $$
actually has a removable singularity at $x=0$.  It can be written in the form
$$ y =  \frac{2k}{1 + \sqrt{1+4k x}}$$
to make this clear.
When $k > 0$ this is defined for $-1/(4k) < x < \infty$, and for $k < 0$ it
is defined for $-\infty < x < -1/(4k)$.